# Transmitting on FRS using a chinese handheld radio

Tags: united-states, legal, frs

I bought a Chinese-made handheld radio with detachable antenna. I programmed it for FRS/GMRS frequencies, but its output is about 3W. Is it illegal? If it is, why and how would anyone find out?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about consumer radio spectrum and rules, and not about amateur radio.

Comment: Hi Kirill. While we welcome some general radio questions, this particular question appears to be outside of the site's scope, which is approximately amateur radio specifically plus the *technology* of radio. Please refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the site's Help Center for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, transmitting with that kind of power is illegal. The max power you may transmit with would be 1/2 of a watt (0.5 watt - 500mw). Their are other factors that make it illegal as well such as the bandwidth you are using while transmitting, spurious emissions, not having a license to transmit on GMRS, and using a detachable antenna. The radio is also most likely not FCC approved. Their are multiple ways you could be "caught". Mainly telling others, interfering with local police / ems / other services, or by a Amateur Radio operator listening (or anyone with a scanner). You could be tracked down via RDF and fined or possibly imprisoned if purposely interfering with other services.

I do not recommend using your radio for FRS / GMRS services.